# MySQL Convert Json Change Column Names

Tags: php, mysql, json

After some MySQL query, I encode my JSON to use in my app like;

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($rows);
    $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->getBody()->write($json);
    return $rows;
```

Here is an example of my JSON;

```
{list_id : "2", list_name : "name here", list_description : "desc here"}
```

**Naturally the export is the same as column name. Like `list_id` is also equals in mysql column name**

I want to change to make it more secure, is there any quick way to do this rather than writing echo manually?

Comment: Use array_map on the $rows and map the  columns however you want.

Comment: Change what? How would it make it more secure? If you want to change property names in the result just alias them in the database query.

Comment: On topic: "I want to change to make it more secure, is there any quick way to do this rather than writing echo manually?" What do you mean?? Side note: This `{list_id : "2", list_name : "name here", list_description : "desc here"}` isn't valid JSON this is `{"list_id" : "2", "list_name" : "name here", "list_description" : "desc here"}` valid JSON.. Check https://jsonlint.com

Comment: You can change the names returned from a SELECT using column aliases - `select 1 as firstField...`

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen that was exactly what I want and easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use column aliases in your SELECT to give the columns a different name in the result set...

```
SELECT list_id as ID, 
         list_name as Name,
         list_description as Description ...
```